# Free software to block Windows software in certain hours

Tags: windows, parental-control, website-blocker

I would like to block certain software (e.g. Outlook and browsers) outside hours that I dedicate for checking emails and browsers. It is like a parental control software for myself but I do not need the security features so hopefully there is a freeware for that. Thought about Windows Parental Control but I am not very keen on sharing my activities and histories with Microsoft.

For reference a paid software is available here but I will prefer to use an freeware for privacy concerns. https://download.cnet.com/HomeGuard-64-bit/3000-2162_4-75630352.html

Comment: You should check tis [link](https://alternativeto.net/software/homeguard-activity-monitor/?license=free&platform=windows)